# How to read files in a directory on Linux?

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, c++17

I am trying to read files in a given directory on Ubuntu 19.04. I am planning to use directory_iterator in standard library. I am using CLion IDE which uses compiler in the directory "usr/bin/c++". I guess this is g++ compiler and the version of g++ is 8.3 in my system. C++ version I am using is C++17.

I was able to run the code successfully on Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. But the code yielded segmentation fault error on Ubuntu while using CLion. The code below is from cppreference page about directory_iterator.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::create_directories("sandbox/a/b");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file1.txt");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file2.txt");
    for(auto& p: fs::directory_iterator("sandbox"))
        std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
    fs::remove_all("sandbox");
}
```

I expected the code to print the files in the given folder but instead I got Segfault.

***Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV).***

What could be the reason behind this issue? Could the problem be related to CMake?

Comment: The code is fine, it could be a bug in the standard library (while not common, they *do* happen). But before we go that far, how do you build your program? What do your `CMakeLists.txt` file look like? With GCC 8, you remember to link with `stdc++fs`?

Comment: As far as I know, the standard `filesystem` is experimental. Use `boost filesystem` instead.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal It was moved from experimental status into the full standard with C++17.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you elaborate on how I can link with stdc++fs? I haven't linked it.

Comment: @Galik It is okay to use reference here.

Comment: You should use `-lstdc++fs` but it should not even compile if you forget that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my cmake file is nothing fancy. It is just the default CMakeLists.txt file provided by CLion.

Comment: Read about the [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) CMake command. But as mentioned by @Galik your program shouldn't build without it (unless you're "lucky" that the features you use are header-only).

Comment: g++ main.cpp -std=c++17 "-lstdc++fs" command does the work as expected on the CLI. While using CMake, adding stdc++fs to target_link_libraries seems to be working as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug in gcc 8.3

If you [run it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H7L5rGoxlwR8x7zc), it fail to link. May be in your environement the bug cause a segfault.

But if you update to gcc 9.1: [it works fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jDV4iTXJy5WOr7nq).

Clang 9 is [fine too](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bPFz8FCuS0VstsiL), but all versions before fail to compile

**Edit:** As said by **Galik** if you add the flag `-lstdc++fs` [it seems to work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/F1BMP49hp01YTYb5)

Source : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

> Notes
>
> Using this library may require additional compiler/linker options. GNU implementation requires linking with -lstdc++fs and LLVM implementation requires linking with -lc++fs